# How to set style for the child nodes in vaadin Treetable?

Tags: vaadin

I need to set style to child nodes in Treetable.

What my need is, when i expand the parent row the newly added child row should be given different color and parent row must have the different color, is there any possibility of doing this ?

Thanks in advance for your kind reply.

regards,
Aravind

Comment: have you tried adding yourChildObject.setStyleName("css property");                                                          ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the follow code...

```
mainTable.setCellStyleGenerator(new TreeTable.CellStyleGenerator() {
  @Override
  public String getStyle(Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
    return "my-css-class";
  }
});
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

1. root nodes - green
2. first child of root - gray
3. rest of children elements - white

this.getTable().setCellStyleGenerator(new Table.CellStyleGenerator() {

```
        boolean rootRow = false;

        @Override
        public String getStyle(Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
            if (getTable().isRoot(itemId)) {
                rootRow = true;
                return "highlight-green";
            } else if (!getTable().isRoot(itemId) && rootRow) {
                rootRow = false;
                return "highlight-gray";
            } else {
                return "v-table-row-odd";
            }

        }
    });
```